# Be + past participle

Tags: adjectives

I have 3 related questions, so I've searched on the internet about this structure but I haven't got any answers. What is the meaning of *Be + past participle,* as in "be done", "be claimed" etc.?

I was trying to create a zero conditional sentence.

> "I will come, when my base upgrades are done properly."

Was that grammatically correct? But I thought it would be better if I put "be done" in the sentence, which will be like this:

> "I will come, when my base be upgraded properly."

Which one is correct?. As that is the first question, the second is:

How the Be + Past participle works?

The third question is, are there any words that describe the condition of a thing already upgraded? Since "upgraded" is a verb, it cannot be used as an adjective. Are there any synonyms of it?.

Comment: Try do research for passive construction

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback, however, I asked about how the form [be] (not a [to be] in general) works, followed by a past participle, such as BE DONE, BE EXCUSED, BE EXPOSED, I am confused by the rules of these following structures, I haven't got any answers yet.

Comment: look what I found in Merriam-Webster be  -used to indicate the identity of a person or thing
—used to describe the qualities of a person or thing
—used to indicate the condition of a person or thing.

Comment: I think you need to check out the full definition of "be" :). I'm not giving answer because Im afraid it'd be wrong

Comment: *I will attend the party if I am invited*.  Or do you want specifically **be** rather than forms of *to be*?  **Upgraded** is a past participle form of the verb 'to upgrade' and it refers to a state of having-been-upgraded and thus can be used as a predicate adjective.

Comment: Hi TRomano, yes I could've used the Upgraded as an adjective as well, but I am unable to find any sources that agree with it, such like, "I will come, when my base is upgraded properly". As far as I know the upgraded is a past verb, it cannot be used as an adjective, or we could actually using past participle as an adjective? Or that was a passive voice?, it has filled my mind, yet I haven't understood how the BE form works, is it a present, past or future, should we add an auxiliary as the tenses of the sentence in conjunction with the verb [BE].

Comment: Sorry for the extensive questions, I am a new learner in English, I hope you would spare a time to help me.

Comment: In the phrase **is upgraded**, the word **upgraded** is not a finite verb.  It is the past participle form of the verb, the complement of finite verb **is**, and a modifier of the subject.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the meaning of Be + past participle, as in "be done", "be claimed" etc.?

The *Past Participle* is the 'ed' or 'en' form of a verb, and it denotes past tense.

The forms of 'be' are as follows -

```
Infinitive           to be
Present              am, is, are
Past                 was, were
Present Participle   being
Past Participle      been
Present Subjunctive  be
Past Subjunctive     were
Imperative           be
```

So, the past participle of 'be' is been.

## Question #1

> Was that grammatically correct? But I thought it would be better if I
>   put "be done" in the sentence, which will be like this:

The first sentence is correct, and in the second, you will have to use the Present from of 'be', which is 'is', the same way that you have done in the first sentence.

So the second sentence should be -

> "I will come, when my base is upgraded properly."

## Question #2

> How <s>the</s> *does the* Be + Past participle <s>works</s> *work*?

Please use the table given above.

## Question #3

> The third question is, are there any words that describe the condition of a thing already upgraded? Since "upgraded" is a verb, it cannot be used as an adjective. Are there any synonyms <s>of</s> for it?

Upgraded is an adjective. Upgrade is a verb. Upgraded is the *past-participle* of upgrade, and this makes it also. So upgraded can be used as a verb as-well-as an adjective.

For example,
Verb form of upgraded -

> I upgraded the water tank. It can now hold more than 2 litres of water

Adjective form of upgraded -

> All of these machines are upgraded computers

## Dictionary result for upgraded

```
/ʌpˈɡreɪdɪd/
adjective
adjective: upgraded

    improved by the addition or replacement of components; raised to a higher standard.
    "upgraded computers"

upgrade
Dictionary result for upgrade
verb
past tense: upgraded; past participle: upgraded
/ʌpˈɡreɪd/

    raise (something) to a higher standard, in particular improve (equipment or machinery) by adding or replacing components.
    "the cost of upgrading each workstation is around £300"
    synonyms:   improve, better, make better, ameliorate, reform, enhance, add to, customize, touch up; More
    rehabilitate, refurbish, recondition, modernize, update, bring up to date, renovate, redecorate, revamp, restore, remodel, redo, brighten up, spruce up;
    bring up to code;
    informaldo up, fix up
    "there are also plans to upgrade the rail system"
    antonyms:   degrade
        raise (an employee) to a higher grade or rank.
        "he will be upgraded from an Undersecretary to a seat at the cabinet table"
        synonyms:   promote, give a higher rank to, place in a higher rank, give promotion to, give a higher position to, elevate, advance, move up, raise, lift, boost, improve the position/status of, aggrandize, exalt; More
        informalkick upstairs;
        archaicprefer
        "some primary school teachers were upgraded to teach in secondary schools"
        antonyms:   downgrade, demote
```

Comment: "The Past Participle is the 'ed' or 'en' form of a verb, and it denotes past tense": wrong. It can be a perfect or passive. Neither of these is necessarily past tense.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

> **Be + past participle = passive voice**

For more information you can search the net for explanations. One option is [here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/passive-voice/)

---

> "I will come, when my base upgrades are done properly."

It is correct.

---

> "I will come, when my base be upgraded properly."

It is incorrect, "to be" is used wrongly in infinitive form. And you changed order of words, it makes no sense. In that sentence, "base" is just an adjective for "upgrades".

---

> are there any words that describe the condition of a thing already upgraded? Since "upgraded" is a verb, it cannot be used as an adjective

No, there is no substitute for "is already upgraded", as far as I know.

"Upgraded" is **a form of a verb** (in this situation, past participle). In your examples, it is not used as an adjective, but as a past participle, as part of the passive voice.

However, in a different context, "upgraded" can be used as an adjective, as in:

> **the upgraded software** is faster than before